# Drafting (of) reports

Tags: prepositions

I want to say that: "I contributed to drafting proposals", and unsure if I use a preposition after "drafting"...

Thanks!

The website wants more symbols, so I keep typing. In fact, I am quite sure that my question is clear.

Comment: Hello, Ms Martin. ELU tries to keep things relatively scholarly (bear with us – at least that's part of the aim), and a reasonable degree of research, where possible, is expected to accompany requests. Not merely an arbitrary number of symbols.  Have you googled "drafting proposals" and "drafting of proposals"? Are both used? Relatively commonly? By sources that sound reasonably competent?

Comment: Why not say it more simply and briefly?  You can say “I helped to draft proposals”.   It avoids the abstraction that litters contemporary English writing.

Comment: Are you using *drafting* as a verb or as an adjective? In other words, are you (1) contributing the activity of drafting several proposals or (2) contributing to several proposal on the subject of drafting?

Answer (score -1):

Usages involving ing-words are complex. Here, firstly, there is the complication that *drafting* may be used adjectivally; examples found on the internet are:

> Courses typically cover various drafting methods ...

[[Study.com … Architectural_Drafting_Technology_Education_and_Training_Program](https://study.com/articles/Architectural_Drafting_Technology_Education_and_Training_Program_Info.html)]

and

> The Secretariat also drew on written submissions received from
>   Governments after that session, containing additional comments and
>   drafting proposals.

[[Reverso.context.net](https://context.reverso.net/%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4/%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B9%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9/drafting+proposals)]

Though this usage is probably not what you’re enquiring about, it needs mentioning as being best avoided as a possibility.

…………………….

The construction ‘**contributed to drafting + NP**’ (some would say **VP** in the following examples, as an object is stipulated) is often used; examples from the internet are:

> MM contributed to drafting, organizing, and critically evaluating all
>   sections of this paper. ZW contributed to drafting sections relating
>   to upper limb control and …

[[Essential Pathways and Circuits of Autism Pathogenesis_edited by Gül Dölen, Mustafa Sahin](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=lf8uDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA52&lpg=PA52&dq=%22contributed+to+drafting%22+-guide&source=bl&ots=b17CnG3fIl&sig=ACfU3U2Bg25oyeaywkgUq2-PrK23-LOeQQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjcrYmknsPjAhXzolwKHQHaDrEQ6AEwCHoECAYQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22contributed%20to%20drafting%22%20-guide&f=false)]

and

> In 2010, as part of the European Progressive Studies Jurists Network,
>   he contributed to drafting proposals for the EU Parliament with regard
>   to an EU draft ...

[[Bloomberg](https://www.bna.com/kaido-knnapas-m73014475110/)]

[Ludwig.com](https://ludwig.guru/s/Contributed+to+forming) has numerous examples of the construction *contributed to + V-ing + object*.

………….

But the construction ‘**contributed to the drafting of + NP**’, reanalysed in some grammars as ‘**contributed to the drafting of + Determiner Phrase**’ is also common (and avoids the ambiguous readings):

> Fieldfisher Paris contributed to the drafting of the second Annual
>   Report on Commodity Analytics and Dynamics In Africa (Arcadia report)

[[Fieldfisher](https://www.fieldfisher.com/media/2017/07/fieldfisher-paris-contributed-to-the-drafting-of-the-second-annual-report-on-commodity-analytics-and-dynamics-in-africa-arcadia-report)].

With 'I contributed to drafting proposals' / 'I contributed to the drafting of proposals' (note that formal writing requires the definite article), while neither is 'incorrect', I'd choose the second variant. While the ambiguity presented by the first variant is probably hardly worth bothering about in this case, I prefer the style of the second in a formal setting.